# Ров и рыть - однокоренные?

Tags: однокоренные-слова, морфемика

Ров и рыть - однокоренные слова? Очевидно, что родственные с общими корнями по происхождению, но можно ли их назвать однокоренными и какой тогда корень? В игре, где нельзя использовать однокоренные слова, можно ли сказать, что ров - это то, что роют?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

И всё-таки рыть-ров - однокоренные, и чередование такое ы//ов имеется

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/915501

Буква «ы» восходит к старославянскому (древнеболгарскому) кириллическому составному знаку ЪІ = Ъ+І (ер + и, откуда и древнее название её еры) Современная форма с конца XIV века проникла в русские рукописи из рукописей балканских (южнославянских). Обозначаемый буквой «ы» гласный ɨ был ещё в праязыке славян. Зачастую происходит из длительного звука *ū [uː], что объясняет чередование ы/ов, ы/у: крыть — кров, слы́шать — слу́шать.

корень здесь ры//ров, как и  кры//кров. крыть/кров, покрыть/покров, сокрыть/сокровенный-однокоренные

Answer (score 1):

> *Ров* и *рыть* - однокоренные слова?

По Тихонову  — **однокоренные**.

См. ***Тихонов А.Н. "Словообразовательный словарь русского языка", М., 1990:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ох уж этот Тихонов. И как он объясняет, какой тут корень? Чередованием Ров/Ры? Тогда надо и "рвать" сюда же.  Еще чередование получится?

Comment: И какой тогда по Тихонову корень у "взрыв"? "В" - суффикс, что ли?! Путаник он великий...

Comment: _И какой тогда по Тихонову корень у "взрыв"?_ === Корень — _**рыв**_, приставка — _**вз**_.

Comment: Т.е. "взрыв" по Тихонову не однокоренной с взрывать?!

Comment: Слово _взрывать_ имеет два значения. Слово _взрыв_   — однокоренное  с _взрывать_ со значением = _взорвать_. И неодноренное с _взрывать_ со значением = _взрыть_.

Comment: Ну это вообще уже дурдом.))) А то, что "рвать" (от корторого "взрыв") и "рыть" ("взрытый") - родственные, никак не останавливает? И где корень "рыв" во "взорванный"?

Comment: _behemothus: А то, что "рвать" (от которого "взрыв") и "рыть" ("взрытый") - родственные, никак не останавливает?_ === 
Если, говоря Вашими словами,  _"ограничиться более близкой родственностью - на уровне, скажем, истории собственно русского языка"_, то "рвать" и "рыть"  — не однокоренные. ////// 

_И где корень "рыв" во "взорванный"? _ === 
 Здесь: взо**рв**анный.

Comment: Ну вот я и говорю, что Тихонов тут крайне непоследователен. Он останавливается на родстве где-то X когда самостоятельного русского ещё не было, А праславянского уже не было. Ни синхрония, ни диахрония, только детей путать. Ладно спасибо, это не квам вопросы, а к Тихонову.

Answer (score -1):

Ну в игре - это вы сами договаривайтесь, по какому правилу определять, что слова однокоренные.
А вообще есть разные подходы. Эти слова родственные, это должны признать все. А вот дальше - уже надо договариваться. Либо считать, что все этимологически родственные слова - однокоренные (корнем тогда надо считать праслявянский морф (?)ru) - тогда однокоренными с ров надо признать еще много всяких слов типа "рвать". Либо ограничиться более близкой родственностью - на уровне, скажем, истории собственно русского язык; это уже более понятно, но все равно предполагает знание этимологии слова, что не всегда возможно обеспечить. Либо, наконец, считать однокоренными только слова, в которых современниками легко выделятся один корень (случаи корневого чередования оговариваются особо). Обычно так и поступают при решении практических задач типа упомянутых игр.

В последнем случае слова рыть и ров просто признаются родственными, но не однокоренными.